# Passing function/method down in my route file react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I did a bunch of searching for the past couple of days and I have tried a bunch of the suggested answers but either can't make sense of the answers or they aren't work or this is just something that can't be done.  I'm building a shopping cart for my site and need to be able to add items to the cart and add that updated quantity to my cart icon.  I tried with redux but could not get it to work so for the time being I want to keep the cart on the main file and pass it down to the components I need it in.  The problem i'm having is i'm trying to pass my addToCart method down and I just can't get it to work

app.js

```
addToCart(id) {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/add-to-cart/${id}`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        }
  }

  render() {
    // const MyProductPage = (props) => {
    //   return (
    //     <TestProducts
    //       addToCart={this.addToCart.bind(this)}
    //       {...props}
    //     />
    //   );
    // }
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          {/* <Route path='/products' render={MyProductPage} /> */}
          <Route path="/products" render={props => <TestProducts addToCart = {this.addToCart} {...props} />} />
          <Route path='/about-us' component={About} />
          <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

testProducts.js

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <section>
          <h1 className='text-center'>Products</h1>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
            {this.state.products.map(product => {
              return (
                <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                  <img className='product' src={product.imagePath} />
                  <a href="#" id='nutritional-facts' className="btn btn-lg" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#allPurposeNutrional'>Nutritional Facts</a>
                  <div className="modal fade" id="allPurposeNutrional" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                      <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                          <h4 className="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nutrional Facts</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body text-center">
                          <img src={product.nutritionImagePath} alt="All Purpose Nutritional Facts" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <h5>All Natural All Purpose</h5>
                  <button onClick={this.props.addToCart(product._id)} >Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
              )
            })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I code-folded as much of the nonsense as I could.  When I have the method in the TestProducts file it works fine so i know that code is good.  When I put the code in the App.js file i don't get any console, i don't see any network request it's just not getting called.

Thank you in advance for all of the help!!!

Comment: I think that your component is way too big, it should be made up of like 2 or 3 smaller components. you're not using a container component either. as a step between your view and your route. as far as adding functionality you want to share across a bunch of components goes I would recommend trying to work redux again. Its a fantastic library thats not all that difficult to work. there are many tutorials on egg head io. check em out.

Comment: thanks for the tips.  I initially started with redux as I have used it in a couple of other projects and like it as well i'm just at a point now where I kind of need/want this to get up and running as quickly as I can but I 100% plan on revisiting redux as it will be a million times easier to pass the data around but i'm using sessions on the server and a couple of other new things and i'm still relatively new.  Again thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I could point out one thing that wouldn't work in your code and I'm guessing you have the same formatted code in your app.

```
<TestProducts addToCart = {this.addToCart} {...props} />}
```

notice that you use spaces between `=` sign

do this:

```
<TestProducts addToCart={this.addToCart} {...props} />}
```

**EDIT:**
I also see that you are calling addToCart straight away, I think it should be

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.addToCart(product._id)} >Add To Cart</button>
```

Comment: appreciate that.  Unfortunately it doesn't help the problem any.

Comment: Awesome.  I'm at least getting the network call now.  I thought when you passed something down as a prop you could just call it straight away.  Thanks for the help i'll have to figure out the other area I messed up now :)

Comment: It will be good idea to split your component into smaller ones. That helpes debugging later on ;)

Comment: yeah i'm porting from html/css to react so it's a work in progress thanks for the help/tips